# How to remove type errors on declaration in PHP (VS Code)

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I got an error in VSCode when I declare a class in PHP. I'd like to precise the type of my variables but I keep getting error :

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'float' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /... on line 12`

Here's my code :

```
class account {
    private float $solde;
    private string $nom;
    private string $prenom;
}
?>
```

I get this error in PHP v8.0.8 and v7.4.21 and didn't find anything on google ...
Thank you for your help !

Comment: This should not throw an error for any PHP version >= 7.4. Have you specified the correct PHP version in your VSCode to begin with ...?

Comment: Hmm, I guess ... i did ```echo phpversion();``` and it says 8.0.8 ! where should i specified it ?

Comment: If you are getting that error you are not running PHP8

Comment: Are you getting this when you try to _run_ the code, or is VSCode showing it to you before that already? If the latter, then you probably need to go change your settings, https://docs.devsense.com/en/vscode/configuration

Comment: My code works when i compile ... It shouldn't if i ran an older php version ? Where should i specify my php version in vscode ?

Comment: I succeed by putting the right php exec path in the settings.json of vscode, thanks for your answers  !